# No se muestran los colores correctos en mi código de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Normalmente el código de javascript en visual studio code se muestra con colores característicos, por ejemplo amarillo para una función o morado para una variable. ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo? , en c# se arregla instalando unas dependencias .net, pero no estoy seguro en javascript. Anexo imagenes de ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]